# try/except not catching NoSuchElementException in loop of Xpath which uses increment of row

Tags: python, selenium, nosuchelementexception

Many thanks.
I am using % format to increment row number inside a for loop to click() on the rows to open new tab, scrape data, close new tab and click on next row. The code runs well until it hits a row that is not a clicklable element. The try/except is not catching exception.

Errormessage:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchEleme ntException: Message: Unable to locate element: .//table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]
```

I am a bit lost here. I am not too sure of how to approach this as the loop runs through the range.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

row_start = 2
x = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//table[1]/tbody/tr'))

    for c in range(row_start, x + 1):
        table_row = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//table[1]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[3]' % c)
        try:
            table_row.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue
        table_row.click()
```

The intent is when a row is not clickable skip that row and continue to the next row.

Answer (score 3):

The exception is from the line above the try. try with the following code.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
row_start = 2 x = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//table[1]/tbody/tr'))
for c in range(row_start, x + 1):
    try:
       table_row = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//table[1]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[3]' % c)
       table_row.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue
```

Comment: Thank You. I hadn't slept for days trying to work this out. Thank You again.